# Find all discrete valuation subrings of $k(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

A discrete valuation ring is a domain $R$ that is noetherian, local (i.e., having exactly one maximal ideal) such that its maximal ideal is principal, and $R$ is not a field.

If $R$ is a domain but not a field, then $R$ is a discrete valuation ring if and only if there exists $t\in R$ irreducible such that for every nonzero $r\in R$, $r$ can be written uniquely as $ut^n$ where $n$ is a nonnegative integer and $u$ is a unit.

In that case, $R$ can be shown to be a principal ideal domain and $t$ is the generator of the unique maximal ideal of $R$.

That's all the theory (concerning DVRs) that I am supposed to know in order to solve the following exercise:

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Find all discrete valuation subrings of $k(x)$ that contain $k$ and whose quotient field is $k(x)$.

This is my attempt: since every element of $k(x)$ can be written as $\frac{f}{g}$ where $f,g\in k[x]$, then we can fix $a\in k$ and consider the ring $R_a$ of all rational functions with denominator that does not vanish at $a$. It is obviously a domain that is not a field, so we have to find an adequate $t$. Indeed, $x-a$ is irreducible, for if $x-a=\frac{f}{g}\times \frac{b}{c}$, then $cg$ does not vanish at $a$ and therefore there is exactly one factor of $x-a$ in the factorization of $bf$; so let's assume that $f(a)=0\neq b(a)$. Therefore $\frac{b}{c}$ is a unit in $R_a$ and $x-a$ is irreducible.

Since $x-a$ is irreducible, we can take $t=x-a$ and we have that $R_a$ satisfies the stated equivalence of being a DVR.

I cannot come with other examples of possible solutions. Also, I have not been able to show that these are the only solutions. How would you solve the exercise?

Comment: The DVR are either $k[x^{-1}]_{(x^{-1})}$ or $k[x]_{(f)} = \{ \frac{u}{v}, u,v \in k[x],v \not \in (f)\}$ with $f \in k[x]$ monic irreducible. Thus for $k = \overline{k}$ the set of DVR of $k(x)$ containing $k$ is identified with $k \cup \infty = \Bbb{P}^1_k$

Comment: Ok, so there is another DVR that I did not come up with. So, why there is not any other?

Comment: Because for a DVR $A$, $x$ or $x^{-1} \in A$, in the first case, with $m$ the maximal ideal of $A$, since $k[x] \subset A$ then $M = m \cap k[x]$ is a prime thus maximal ideal of $k[x]$, so $M = (f)$,  $A \supset k[x]_{(f)}$ and $A = k[x]_{(f)}$  since the latter is a DVR with the same fraction field as $A$. Here with DVR I mean a subring containing $k$ with fraction field $k(x)$ and a unique maximal ideal which is principal. There are more DVR with smaller fraction field: $k[\frac{u}{v }(x-a)^n]_{\frac{u}{v }(x-a)^n}, u(a),v(a) \ne 0$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. The only argument I am missing is "$x$ or $x^{.1}\in A$". I suppose it should have to do with the equality $\text{Frac}(A)=k(x)$, but I am not succeeding in proving it.

Comment: The principal maximal ideal of $A$ induces a discrete valuation $v$, let $\pi \in A, v(\pi) = 1$, $A$ has a unique prime ideal means $Frac(A) = A[\pi^{-1}]$ so that $A = \{ f \in Frac(A),v(f) \ge 0\}$. If $Frac(A) = k(x)$ then one of $x,x^{-1}$ has non-negative valuation. For the case where $Frac(A)$ is a subfield of $k(x)$ we need the theorem that any subfield (containing $k$) is of the form $k(f)$ in which case $A = k[f]_{(f-c)}$ or $A=k[f^{-1}]_{(f^{-1})}$.

Comment: Thank you, that was brilliant. Do not worry about that last case because the exercise only deals with $Frac(A)=k(x)$. Ok... now we (you) have handled the case when $x\in A$. If $x^{-1}\in A$ then $k[x^{-1}]\subset A$. If we were able to show that $k[x^{-1}]_{(x^{-1})}\subset A$ and the first maximal is contained in the second one, then I would be done. (I am not sure whether I am getting right the definition of $k[x^{-1}]_{(x^{-1})}$).